# If $\sin \theta =37$ then find value of $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

This problem I encountered in my maths book.I know how to find theta which are very basic (30 and 60 and 45).please help me.

Comment: If $\sin(\theta)=37$, then, according to wolfram alpha, $\theta \approx 1.57 - 4.3 i + 2 \pi k,\, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I suppose this isn't what you want.

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you mean $\sin(37^\circ)$ or $\sin\theta=37$ or $\sin(37)$ in the title?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to find the value of $\sin(37)$ without a calculator? Equally, maybe you intended to write $\sin^{-1}\theta=37$

Comment: I am guessing that what is meant is, find the sine of $37°$.  There is none in terms of algebraic functions unless you are into complex radicals.  You get really close by just calling it $0.6$ as $37°$ is near the smaller acute angle in the $3-4-5$ right triangle.

Comment: Actually I want the formula to find any sin ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\sin\theta = n$, then $\theta = \arcsin n$. However you should notice $\arcsin : [-1,1] \to [-90^\circ, 90^\circ]$, meaning $37$ is not within the domain of $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 4):

Sine takes on values between $-1$ and $1$ (at least for real valued inputs).

So, $\sin \theta = 37$ has no real solution.

Comment: -1 From OP's explanation of the problem it's clear that the equation in the title is badly written. They mention that they can do the problem for 30, 45 and 60. So you're not addressing their actual question.

Comment: @Hugh I object. For me, it is entirely not clear what does OP actually want, since he repeats "find theta" several times (presumably, $\theta$ is an angle). It may happen that the question was interpreted wrong, or there is a typo in the book. As written, this answer perfectly answers the question.

Comment: @Hugh from the wording "find value of theta" I thought it was pretty clear that he meant $\sin\theta = 37$

Comment: @Dando if that were the case why would they say that solving $\sin \theta=45$ is basic?

Comment: @lisyarus If the question isn't clear you should ask for explanation in the comments rather than posting an answer

Comment: @Hugh He could mean $\sin \theta = \frac 1 2$ or $\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$. I would still find it plausible to say "i know how to find the basic theta (30, 45, 60)...

Comment: @Hugh It could mean "I know how to solve $\sin(\theta)=c$ when $\theta=30,45,60$", that is, when $c = {1\over \sqrt 2}, {2 \over \sqrt 2},  {3 \over \sqrt 2}$.

Comment: @Hugh Whether the question is clear or not is one's personal opinion. I didn't post the answer, since for me it is unclear. But I agree that it can be considered clear, yet strange. It was clear for Batman, and he posted a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with things like half- and double-angle formulas, then you can find more general identities that'll relate, for instance, $\sin \theta, \cos \theta$ with $\sin (\theta / n)$ for appropriate numbers, as well as expressions of $\sin n \theta$ in terms of $\sin \theta, \cos \theta$. These could tell you $\sin$ for $37^{\circ}$, but they'll be tedious.

Also, a piece of advice with how you posed your question. If I read you correctly, you're asking "What is the exact value of $\sin \theta$ when $\theta = 37^{\circ}$?" But what you wrote ("If $ \sin \theta = 37$ then find value of $\theta$") was construed by many as asking, "For what angle $\theta$ is $\sin \theta = 37$?", i.e. trying to solve the equation $\sin (\theta) = 37$. This equation, as many pointed out, does not have a real solution, so we must resort to the complex numbers to solve it. You'd do well to (1) take care to phrase your question carefully and clearly so you don't just get unhelpful answers to questions you didn't mean to ask, and (2) get basically familiar with Mathjax, which is not only aesthetically pleasing, but will help you write your question more clearly. A major part of math is learning how to communicate it, and good communication skills will make benefitting from this site a lot easier, as well as help you with your math studies in general.